# "Wrong file type, please select again" when choosing a ringtone

Tags: notifications, nexus-5, ringtone

I have a Nexus 5, all my ringtones and notification sounds returned to default, and when I try to set any file as a sound I get this message:

> Wrong file type, please select again

I get the same message no matter what file type I choose, including the files that were my sounds until this morning. I tried to delete cache memory and reboot but that did nothing.

Comment: Maybe related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85592/ringtones-incompatible-with-custom-rom-how-to-improve-compatibility

Comment: As a temporary solution I can only suggest you get a ringtone app that allows you to set ringtones and use it just for that, I've had this issue for a while and nothing solves the actual problem. Just curious. Have you done a firmware update before the problem occurred?

Answer (score 7):

José Mejuto Was correct in his 2nd Point.

deleting the /.nomedia file has no effect.

- 1: Go to "Settings -> Apps (All) -> Media storage"
- 2: Clear Cache & Data
- 3: Change your ring tone or notification tone

Thanks José :)

Comment: On newer versions of Android, you may have to pull down the menu on the `Apps` list and select `Show system` in order for `Media Storage` to show up.

Answer (score 3):

Today my Nexus 5 starts to do the same, default Ringtone and "Wrong file type, please select again". After several hours trying different solutions I came to the conclusion that the problem is in -or related to- the "Google Play Music" which do not work for local files anymore. I was able to finally get my custom ring tones again to life performing two tasks, but I do not known which one solves the problem because a reboot is needed and I perform both before reboot.

1) In my case in the root of the SD card there was a ".nomedia" file which could prevent multimedia use in this folder and below. So try to delete this file and reboot terminal, then try to set a custom ring tone.

Note: My Nexus is in spanish, and options could have a different name.

2)  I suspect that multimedia SQLite database was corrupted in some way, so I went to **Settings -> Applications -> "Almacenamiento de medios" (Maybe Media storage? com.android.providers.media)** and deleted data, then reboot.

After the reboot all multimedia data was rescanned and I was able to change the ring tone again.

Note: I had detected that my old custom tone for notifications was gone, the file was gone and I was unable to find it in my storage media.

Answer (score 1):

Copy to existing Ringtones folder on device, go to choose ringtone and select media storage and amongst the device ringtone selection will be your file

Answer (score 1):

Please change your audio file format to .wav; now you give it a try to assign the ringtone. It will work! Since, I had this same issue when I tried to assign a ringtone in an .mp3 file. Then, I changed the .mp3 format to .wav format; it works!

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Moto G and I had the same problem. Solution for me was to

1. Download a file manager app
2. Save the ringtone `mp3` file in my `music` folder
3. In `settings\ringtones` (in the file manager), select your ringtone from the `music` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I stayed with the original folder named "Ringtones" and just renamed it to "ringtones" [lowercase]. 
Rebooted. 
Problem Solved